# Dynamic-Jasper Struts2 Netbean configuration

Tags: struts2, dynamic-jasper

I am configuring the `dynamicjasper` to my `struts2` but it raises an error. First of all I using the following jar files:

```
DynamicJasper-4.0.3
DynamicJasper-4.0.3-javadoc
DynamicJasper-4.0.3-sources
DynamicJasper-4.0.3-tests
DynamicJasper-4.0.3-test-sources
DynamicJasper-Struts2-1.3
jasperreports-4.7.0
struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.0.11.1-sources

<result-types> 
     <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
     <result-type name="redirectAction" 
class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult"/>
     <result-type name="dynamic-jasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.struts2.DJStruts2Result"/>
</result-types>

<action name="dynamicreport" class="ActionClass.DynamicJasperAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack"/>
            <param name="operation">showreport</param>
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="dynamic-jasper">
                 <param name="format">PDF</param>
            </result>
</action>
```

When I run the application it displays the following error in glass fish 3+ output window:

```
INFO: ERROR  (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:38) - Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/G:/Project/IG/LIMSs/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:2996:78

Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'dynamic-jasper' mapped with name 'SUCCESS'.  Did you mean 'dynamicJasper'? - result - file:/G:/Project/IG/LIMSs/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:2999:58
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:645)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:379)
    ... 57 more

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [IMsys] at [/LIMSs]
INFO: IMsys was successfully deployed in 71,796 milliseconds.
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

Error in browser as follows:

```
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
root cause
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

I'm not sure how to configure the dynamic jasper, can you advise?

Comment: `Did you mean 'dynamicJasper'?`.

Answer (score 0):

just download DynamicJasper-4.0.3-test-sources.jar  instead of DynamicJasper-4.0.3-test.jar then add the problem is solved.